# How do I close / get rid of the right hand column in Yahoo! mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

How do I close / get rid of the right hand column in Yahoo! mail?

I've put a red box around what I want to remove.

It's just using up space on the screen unnecessarily.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of that column with a little bit of JavaScript. In Yahoo! Mail Basic, the following command will hide that column, making the `content` column (the middle column) extend to the right side of the screen:

```
document.getElementById('slot_LREC').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
```

Running that command from the address bar (preceded by `javascript:`) or from the console will hide the column, but it won't be persistent -- the column will reappear as soon as you reload the page.

To make the change persistent, you can create a *web browser extension* that will automatically run that bit of code when you are on a Yahoo! Mail page. The steps for creating a browser extension vary depending on which browser you are using, but the JavaScript bit is the same.

These articles can walk you through the process of creating a browser extension:

#### Chrome:

- [Getting Started Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) (Google)
- [How to Create a Chrome Extension in 10 Minutes Flat](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/) (SitePoint)

#### Firefox:

- [Your first extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) (Mozilla)
- [Browser Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions) (Mozilla)

---

If you are using AdBlock Plus, you can have it hide the column for you. See [ADP's instructions for using a filter to hide specific elements](https://help.eyeo.com/en/adblockplus/how-to-write-filters#elemhide) to see how to do that.

Comment: thanks i'll test this as soon as i can